# How to set sort order for build jobs in lists? Jenkins seems to sort by 'Console' per default, why?

Tags: jenkins

In our Jenkins the build jobs shown in the lists are sorted by 'Console'. WHY? Is it a kind of Jenkins default?

How can we change the default to 'sort by name'?

Comment: How do you want to sort it then?

Comment: After opening a view I want that the build jobs shown in the view are sorted by name.

Comment: Do you mean the job list under list view?

Comment: Exactly. I mean views of type 'List View'.